# Filtering Items returns all items

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

I'm trying to filter an array to get matched Id item(s) but getting all items instead of the matched item(s).

I have an array of items which look like

```
[{
    itemId: '3ssddsf1d',
    itemCode: '7ceda3ce4f',
    familyCode: 'online_food_ordering',
    attributes: {
        logoUrl: '',
        tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
        cuisines: ['Italian'],
        headlines: ['Order online']
    }, {
    itemId: 'aasdfsfa',
    itemCode: '9c224f',
    familyCode: '',
    attributes: {
        logoUrl: '',
        tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
        cuisines: ['Spanish'],
        headlines: []
    },
 {
    itemId: 'aafdsf',
    itemCode: '9fsdgc224f',
    familyCode: '',
    attributes: {
        logoUrl: '',
        tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
        cuisines: ['Mexican'],
        headlines: []
    }
]
```

and want to filter with `matchedIds` (array)

```
    const matchedIds = ['aasdfsfa','udfjasafshlasgiafl']

    items.filter((item: IItem) => {
        return matchedIds.filter((id: string) => {
            return id === item.itemId;
        });
    });
```

expected only

```
[{
    itemId: 'aasdfsfa',
    itemCode: '9c224f',
    familyCode: '',
    attributes: {
        logoUrl: '',
        tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
        cuisines: ['Spanish'],
        headlines: []
}]
```

but returns all items.

Am I missing something? any help would be grateful!

sorry, my bad seems duplicated question..  thanks for letting me know

Comment: Why do you have two filters? The nested one returns an array which I assume gets interpreted as true for all items

Comment: because the result of `return matchedIds.filter` will be `[]` or `[non-empty]`, I prefer this way: convert `const matchedIds = ['aasdfsfa','udfjasafshlasgiafl']` to one `new Set(['aasdfsfa','udfjasafshlasgiafl'])`, then check if ID in this Set()

Comment: couldn't you just have the inner one and check if `items.includes(item.itemId)`?

Comment: The function passed to `filter` should return a Boolean value indicating if the value should be included or not. The outer `filter` function is returning an array. Make it return a Boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the code and I believe that you should be doing the following in order to that filter work:

```js
const filtered = items.filter((a) => {
    return matchedIds.includes(a.itemId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map to iterate through the array and then use filter to check for match

```js
array=[{
  itemId: '3ssddsf1d',
  itemCode: '7ceda3ce4f',
  familyCode: 'online_food_ordering',
  attributes: {
      logoUrl: '',
      tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
      cuisines: ['Italian'],
      headlines: ['Order online']
  }
}, 
{
  itemId: 'aasdfsfa',
  itemCode: '9c224f',
  familyCode: '',
  attributes: {
      logoUrl: '',
      tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
      cuisines: ['Spanish'],
      headlines: []
  },
},
{
  itemId: 'aafdsf',
  itemCode: '9fsdgc224f',
  familyCode: '',
  attributes: {
      logoUrl: '',
      tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
      cuisines: ['Mexican'],
      headlines: []
  }
}
]
const matchedIds = ['aasdfsfa','udfjasafshlasgiafl']


result=array.filter(o=>matchedIds.some(i=>i==o.itemId))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: why the downvote ??!!!

Comment: Maybe because it is wrong.

Comment: can you explain to me what's wrong with the answer I would like to know

Comment: My apologies I realise where I gone wrong I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
sample.filter( item => item.itemId === id )
```

With array

```
sample.filter( item => idArr.find(id => item.itemId === id) ) )
```

Working example:

```js
const sample = [
    {
      itemId: '3ssddsf1d',
      itemCode: '7ceda3ce4f',
      familyCode: 'online_food_ordering',
      attributes: {
          logoUrl: '',
          tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
          cuisines: ['Italian'],
          headlines: ['Order online']
      } 
    }, {
      itemId: 'aasdfsfa',
      itemCode: '9c224f',
      familyCode: '',
      attributes: {
          logoUrl: '',
          tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
          cuisines: ['Spanish'],
          headlines: []
      }
    }, {
      itemId: 'aafdsf',
      itemCode: '9fsdgc224f',
      familyCode: '',
      attributes: {
          logoUrl: '',
          tagline: 'Food. Delivered.',
          cuisines: ['Mexican'],
          headlines: []
      }
    }
];

const id = 'aasdfsfa';
const idArr = ['aasdfsfa', 'aafdsf'];

console.log( sample.filter( item => item.itemId === id ) );
console.log('array', sample.filter( item => idArr.find(id => item.itemId === id) ) )
```

Comment: The problem is they want to check for multiple IDs

Comment: `const matchedIds = ['aasdfsfa','udfjasafshlasgiafl']` ids are array so that i'm confusing

Comment: I see, missed that. see updated answer.